# ALL React list items change color when ONE is hovered. Why not just the ONE?

Tags: reactjs

I have designed a page in React where all styled colors change, depending on whether the user is signed in or not. I have been successful with the entire page except when it comes to changing the color of the links on hover. As is, when a link is hovered, the entire set of links is changing color, rather than just the one link. Running map() on each item I thought would produce the desired effect *on each item* but it is not working that way. I can't see why this code doesn't work. (All my colors are being applied in-line)

```
const links = [
  {
    link: 'Category 1',
  },
  {
    link: 'Category 2',
  },
  {
    link: 'Category 3',
  },
];
function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurentUser] = useState(false);
  const [noUserColors, setNoUserColors] = useState('green');

  const handleNoUserMouseEnter = () => {
    setNoUserColors('blue');
  };

  const handleNoUserMouseLeave = () => {
    setNoUserColors('green');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {links.map((link) => {
          return (
            <li>
              {currentUser || (
                <a
                  style={{ color: noUserColors }}
                  onMouseEnter={handleNoUserMouseEnter}
                  onMouseLeave={handleNoUserMouseLeave}
                >
                  {link.link}
                </a>
              )}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}``
```

Comment: You have a boolean `currentUser` which is either `true` or `false`. You need to make a comparison to the `link` variable instead of just a default boolean value. In a more react fashion, you could make list/link components  (with `<li>`) that simply change color when hovered, instead of handling this in the component aggregating all those `<li>` elements.

Comment: It's cos you only have 1 state value to handle multiple interactions in a list. Mouse over any one will activate the same across all in the list. Consider updating your state to contain a list. And update individual state in a list. Initialise something like: const [linkColors, setLinkColors] = useState(links.map(() => 'green')); And could update as: const newColors = [...linkColors];
    newColors[index] = 'blue';
    setLinkColors(newColors);

Comment: Just as a further note: this behavior can be 100% CSS managed through the use of `:hover`. No javascript nor react needed, just appropriate selectors (so perhaps class names for some tags). Letting CSS handle some things instead of javascript can save a lot of processing in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a list of items, each item could have its own state.
And when you mouse over could update only the item in that particular index.

So for example could consider initialising everything as green as follows.

```
const [linkColors, setLinkColors] = useState(links.map(() => 'green'));
```

Then on mouse over could update as follows:

```
const newColors = [...linkColors]; // get all state values so that we don't override everything.
newColors[index] = 'blue'; // only update on the index you mouse over.
setLinkColors(newColors); // set back the state.
```